# Replaced ignition cylinder, car wont turn over or crank

Tags: starting, ignition, no-crank-no-start

I have a 2007 chevrolet malibu. I have been having trouble for a while with having to turn the key a few times before it would crank until it finally quit cranking at all. I replaced the ignition switch and that didn't fix it. Then I replaced the ignition lock cylinder and done the reset. The dashlights come on but it still won't turn over or crank. I have also tested the starter and it is good. Do you have any suggestions for what I need to try next?

Comment: When you try to crank the engine, do you hear the starter relay "click"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the starter is good, check the battery and starter connections. Then check that the engines earth strap has a good contact and is tight.